# Get url parameters of link and append the parameters to all subnav urls on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck on.when i click on hotel URL it navigates to hotel site(this site url contains form parameters(/overview?brand_id=hotel&...) and it also contains subnav in page).

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="\Overview">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="\about">about</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">parent<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="\All">All</a></li>
     <li><a href="\Golf">Golf</a></li>
     <li><a href="\Spa">Spa</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

if I have url: http://www.read.com/overview?brand_id=hotel&...

and i would need get the parameters from the URL and append to all sub nav URLs when someone clicks on the link how would I?

For example I want it to now be: http://www.read1.com/about?brand_id=hotel&...

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: You wanna use jquery ?

Comment: If you make a post I think that you would to find somebody to HELP you to solve the problem. Help means that don't make for you the code. I suggest you first to check well your post for let the people understand what you need. You speak to pass the parameter to subnav 'subnav'  but in your example use the main nav 'about?' than in the code the domain is "www.read.com" and in your example become "www.read1.com". And as last point and not less important, if you hope to receive the post after published check if somebody reply or ask you more info, not just post and leave!

Comment: @DaebakDo jquery is also noissue, i almost expressed at i need

Comment: in short and clear, i have a hotel site URL which contain form parameters as http://www.hotel.com/overview?brand_id=hotel&...  and here form parameters(?brand_id=hotel&...) which are appending to hotel site should be appended to the href tag in navigation menu